# Optimizing range join (x between a and b) in MariaDB

Tags: performance, optimization, join, mariadb, mariadb-5.5, query-performance

My query has a join using a BETWEEN clause and it causes a full table scan to occur if I understand the EXPLAIN output correctly.

### Query

```sql
EXPLAIN
 SELECT g.id, g.name, c.id AS child_id, c.date
   FROM g
   JOIN c
     ON c.parent_id = g.id
    AND c.date BETWEEN g.start_date AND g.end_date;
```

### Keys

- Primary key of `g`: (id, start_date)
- Primary key of `c`: (id)
- Foreign key on `c.parent_id references g.id`
- Index on `c`: (parent_id)

### EXPLAIN output

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+-------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type |   possible_keys   |        key        | key_len |     ref     | rows  | filtered |    Extra    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+-------------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | g     | ALL  | PRIMARY           |                   |         |             | 18342 |      100 | ""          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ref  | idx_parent_id     | idx_parent_id     |       4 | square.g.id |     3 |      100 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+-------------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

In the `g` (parent) table, there are no rows that overlap each other in start/end date for a given ID but the database would not know that since there is no way to indicate it as far as I know.

All of the date columns are of type `date`.

How can I avoid a full table scan, or if I can't, what can I do to improve the performance? As of now there are approximately 250k rows in the `c` table and 25.7k rows in the `g` table.

This query is used to create a view, and in the application there are many queries that select from this view and joins it with other tables, so it is very important to optimize this view.

---

What has been tried as per comments:

- Adding indices `g (id, start_date, end_date)` and `c (parent_id, date)`
- Replacing `c.date BETWEEN g.start_date AND g.end_date` with `g.start_date <= c.date AND c.date <= g.end_date`

Comment: Try to create indices `c (parent_id, date)` and `g (id, start_date, end_date`.

Comment: @Akina I just tried it. Both indices showed up in the `possible_keys` but they weren't used.

Comment: How many records does each table stores? What part of records does the query selects? and what part if do not check g.end_date? Try to replace BETWEEN with 2 unequiations...

Comment: @Akina On the QA server that I am testing on, `c` has 77k rows and `g` has ~19k rows. On production we are looking at around 250k rows and 26k rows, respectively. This number will only grow over time. I'm not sure what you mean by "what part of records", I'm still encountering this even if I select one column from each table. Replacing the BETWEEN with <= AND >= did not make a difference in the explain output.

Comment: What if to hint server to read `c` before `g`? i.e. `FROM с STRAIGHT_JOIN g`

Comment: @Akina that changes the full table scan to take place on the other table, depending on the order of the tables (since `STRAIGHT_JOIN` forces the order)